# как отключать таймер setInterval ? Работают параллельно несколько

Tags: javascript, jquery

сразу таймер запускается потом если время уходит то он клацает на #next,
если он все делает сам то норма, а если я не дождусь таймера клацну на #next то таймер, что работал будет работать и появится новый т.е (как и должен быть а старый должен же уже не работать, если несколько раз клацну то параллельно будет много работать к примеру на одном осталось 2 сек, на другом 5 сек на последнем 8  сек и т.д.

```js
$(".next").click(function () {
  timerSite = function(status) {
          if (status) {
              const secondsToAnswer = 10; // Количество секунд для ответа
              let timeLeft = secondsToAnswer;
              const timer = setInterval(function(){
                if (timeLeft > 0) { // На последней секунде
                  $('.timer').text(timeLeft + ' сек');
                  timeLeft--;
                } else {
                  $('.timer').text('Время вышло');
                  $('#next').click();
                   clearInterval(timer);
                }
              }, 1000);
          }else {
              clearInterval(timer);
          }
        }
        //пробовал передать false выдает ошибку :
  //Uncaught ReferenceError: timer is not defined
        timerSite(false);

        //тут он запускается
        timerSite(true);
      
});
```

Answer (score 2):

У вас константа `timer` инициализируется внутри условия когда оно истинно, т.е. когда передаёте в функцию `true`. Следовательно когда передаёте `false` функция пытаемся сбросить несуществующий таймер

Comment: ну так его сбросить?

Comment: Попробуйте объявить эту константу в начале функции, а не в условии. А присвоить сам таймер уже в условии. Хотя даже не так, чтобы таймер был глобальным нужно объявить эту переменную за пределами функции

Comment: Снаружи `$(".next").click(function () {`.

Comment: не совсем понятно вот эта функция timerSite(true); она вызывается в разных местах поэтому счетчик должен быть в ней

Comment: Если в разных местах, но в пределах одного файла, то это нормальная практика. Объяви константу в самом начале файла.

Comment: Поставьте галочку если ответ вам помог )